# Find critical points of the functional $I[y] = c \int_0^L y(y')^3 dx$

Tags: derivatives, calculus-of-variations

> Find critical points of the functional
>
> $I[y] = c \int_0^L y(y')^3 dx$ with $y(0)=0$ and $y(L)=R$

Euler-Lagrange equation:
I arrive at $(y')^3+3yy'y''=0$ and so solve $y'=0$ and $(y')^2+3yy''=0.$

First one is easy to solve: $y=c$.

Second one I have no idea to solve (could you explain the method please)
^
using wolfram I get $y=a(b+4x)^{\frac{3}{4}}$

Using the conditions I think $b=0, a=\frac{R}{(4L)^{\frac{3}{4}}}$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

$$(y')^2+3yy''=0$$
$$1-3y\frac{d(1/y')}{dx}=0$$
$$1-3y\frac{d(1/y')}{dy}y'=0$$
$$\frac{dy}{3y}=\frac{d(1/y')}{1/y'}$$
$$y^{1/3}=\frac{c}{y'}$$

You can take it from here